# Why do I get ErrorException from AuthManager?

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to authenticate users in Laravel with Ajax form.  After the user is authenticated, he is redirected to front page.  On this front page, I am trying to set and use the model method and display name of user - like  `Auth::model_name()->method`, but it is showing this error:

> ErrorException in AuthManager php call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard'

Front end code:

```
if (!Auth::check()){
<a href="#" class="login-menu hide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login2</a> 
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle show" data-toggle="dropdown">

{{ Auth::Hublancers_users()->username }} 
}
else{ 
<a href="{{ route('Login') }}" class="login-menu show">Login</a> 
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hide" data-toggle="dropdown">
}
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show code that gives this error

Comment: Front end code :: 

if (!Auth::check())

 <a href="#" class="login-menu hide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login2</a>

 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle show" data-toggle="dropdown">
                              {{ Auth::Hublancers_users()->username }}

 else

 <a href="{{ route('Login') }}" class="login-menu show">Login</a>
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hide" data-toggle="dropdown">

Comment: Please edit your post and add this code there.

Comment: @Calvin what's Hublancers_users. please update your question with, model, view, controller and any other relevant info